# Exercise 8.1.A of Vakil's FOAG

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In [Vakil's FOAG](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf), definition 8.1.1 reads as

A morphism $\pi : X \to Y$ of schemes is a **closed embedding** if

1. $\pi$ is affine, i.e., for every affine open subset $\mathrm{Spec} B$ of $Y$, 
   $\pi^{-1}\mathrm{Spec} B \cong \mathrm{Spec} A$ is affine open in $X$.
2. And the induced morphism $\mathrm{Spec} A \to \mathrm{Spec} B$ on global section is a surjective map $B \to A$

Then, in **Exercise 8.1.A**, I'm asked to show that the closed embedding $\pi$ identifies the topological space
of $X$ with a closed subset of the topological space of $Y$.

The text uses the word **"identify"**. I believe that by using "identify" he means 
"homeomorphic" as in the affine case: if we have a surjective ring map $B \to B/I$, then we have an induced map $\mathrm{Spec} B/I \to \mathrm{Spec} B$ which is a homeomorphism from $\mathrm{Spec} B/I$ to the closed subset $V(I)$ of $\mathrm{Spec} B$.

**The question is I don't know how to show this.**

I have some thoughts:

- I've managed to show that **$\pi$ is injective**: Take an affine open $\mathrm{Spec} B$ of $Y$, let $\mathrm{Spec} A = \pi^{-1}\mathrm{Spec}B$. By definition, on global sections, $\pi^\# : B \to A$ is surjective. Since we have the equivalence between category of affine schemes and rings, $\pi : \mathrm{Spec}A \to \mathrm{Spec}B$ is exactly induced by $\pi^\# : B \to A$. Since $\pi^\#$ is surjective, we know that $\pi^\#$ induces homeomorphism from $\mathrm{Spec}A$ to a closed subset of $\mathrm{Spec}B$, in particular, $\pi : \mathrm{Spec}A \to \mathrm{Spec}B$ is injective.
- By definition, $\pi$ is continuous, and we have just shown $\pi$ is injective. 
  So it suffices to show that $\pi$ takes closed subsets of $X$ to closed subsets of 
  $Y$.

By arguments above, we only know that $\pi$ takes each piece of some affine open cover of $X$ to some closed subset of affine open of $Y$. 
How can one take care of this gap, or should I try some different way?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This is the correct strategy. You are only missing one key idea: in a topological space $X$, it is often the case that if one has an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ and one wants to verify a property of a set $S$, one can verify this property on each $U_i$ and then put it together. First, prove this in the case that you're talking about closedness, then apply it to the problem at hand by picking a nice open cover.